# uiautomatorviewer file is not present. Instead uiautomatorviewer.jar is available

Tags: android, automation, android-uiautomator, uiautomatorviewer

I want to automate android app. For that I need `uiautomatorview`.
But this SDK has not provided TOOLS folder. 
Instead, uiautomatorviewer.jar file is present inside `Android/sdk/platforms/android-29`.

Can someone help me out as I've not found solution for this over google

Answer (score 0):

Search uiautomatorviewer directly in

```
C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\
```

Then, in search results, you will be able to see the exact location for the file. For me, the file was located at:

```
C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools\bin
```